# Insert data into sqlite in-memory database

Tags: c#, sqlite, in-memory-database

So I have a in-memory database and I'm trying to insert data into the table and it's not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;");

connection.Open();

string sql = "CREATE TABLE  recently_viewed(movieid INTEGER,picture TEXT)";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

using ( command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT into recently_viewed(movieid ,picture) values(@movieid,@picture)";
    command.Prepare();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieid", id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", picture);
}

string   count_table = " SELECT count(*) FROM recently_viewed";

SQLiteCommand   com3 = new SQLiteCommand(count_table, connection);

int   ctable = Convert.ToInt32(com3.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Response.Write(ctable);

connection.Close();
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a description of a problem. Please tell us **what** doesn't work, **what happens** when you run it, and any exceptions you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed from your code that this line:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is called only once. What happens when you do:

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;");

connection.Open();

string sql = "CREATE TABLE  recently_viewed(movieid INTEGER,picture TEXT)";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

using ( command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT into recently_viewed(movieid ,picture) values(@movieid,@picture)";
    command.Prepare();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieid", id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", picture);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


string   count_table = " SELECT count(*) FROM recently_viewed";

SQLiteCommand   com3 = new SQLiteCommand(count_table, connection);
com3.ExecuteNonQuery();

int   ctable = Convert.ToInt32(com3.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Response.Write(ctable);

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Put the second ExecuteNonQuery inside the using block; after that block `command` will be `Dispose`d.