# C# SQLite insert not working

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into an SQLite file but when I try to do so nothing gets added to the file, it's the first time I deal with SQLite so not quite sure I'm doing it right. Please ask if any other information is needed.

Here is the source code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Readlines();
        }

        public void Readlines()
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Projects\GFKMVC\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Opgave001.txt");
            Shift shift = new Shift();
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("TimePlan.sqlite");
            SQLiteConnection dbcon;
            dbcon = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=TimePlan.sqlite;Version=3;");
            dbcon.Open();
            //string DropTable = "DROP DATABASE TimePlane.sqlite";
            //SQLiteCommand dropCom = new SQLiteCommand(DropTable, dbcon);
            //dropCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE Shifts (EmployeeID INT, Date DATETIME, StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Break INT)";
            SQLiteCommand createCom = new SQLiteCommand(CreateTable, dbcon);
            createCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] fields = line.Split(';');
                shift.EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(fields[0]);
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                shift.Date = dt;
                DateTime st = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[2], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                shift.StartTime = st;
                DateTime et = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[3], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                shift.EndTime = et;
                shift.Break = Int32.Parse(fields[4]);
                string InsertSql = "INSERT INTO Shifts (EmployeeID, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Break) values ("+shift.EmployeeID+","+shift.StartTime+","+shift.EndTime+","+shift.Break+")";
                SQLiteCommand InsertCom = new SQLiteCommand(InsertSql, dbcon);
                InsertCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            dbcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any error message? Exceptions? How do you check if the table is empty or not?

Comment: Check to see if any of the parameter values you are passing to the sql string such as shift.EmployeeID, shift.StartTime etc are NULL

Comment: @Steve I get this: SQL logic error or missing database
near "06": syntax error.

I checked by locating the db file in my system and checking it via a sqlite browser.

Comment: Probably this error is caused by your string concatenation of the insert values. Something is not in the correct format and the insert fails. You need to learn how to use a parameterized query

Comment: @Steve can you give an example ?

Comment: @MattBaech can  you change your code to use the following 
`using(){ }` for your database objects also if SqLite can handle Parameters, change that INSERT statement to use Parameters....

Comment: @MethodMan What exactly would you want the using to surround ? 
Also, I am ashamed to say that I don't understand to use parameterized queries

Comment: @MattBaech then do some google searching if you are not familiar with using statement in C# code then I am not going to explain you would not understand anyway.. also `I don't understand to use parameterized queries` is really not productive on your part.. that's what MSDN and Google is used for.. a good learning tool..

Comment: here is a great example on how to use it @MattBaech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057848/insert-data-into-sqlite-in-memory-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parameterized query could help a lot avoiding problems in parsing input values (and just for fun read about [Sql Injection here](http://xkcd.com/327/))

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(';');
    shift.EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(fields[0]);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.Date = dt;
    DateTime st = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[2], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.StartTime = st;
    DateTime et = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[3], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.EndTime = et;
    shift.Break = Int32.Parse(fields[4]);
    string InsertSql = @"INSERT INTO Shifts 
                        (EmployeeID, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Break) 
                        values ($eid, $date, $stime, $etime, $break)";

    SQLiteCommand InsertCom = new SQLiteCommand(InsertSql, dbcon);
    InsertCom.Parameters.Add("$eid", DbType.Int32).Value = shift.EmployeeID;
    InsertCom.Parameters.Add("$date", DbType.Date).Value = shift.Date ;
    InsertCom.Parameters.Add("$stime", DbType.Time).Value = shift.StartTime ;
    InsertCom.Parameters.Add("$etime", DbType.Time).Value = shift.EndTime;
    InsertCom.Parameters.Add("$break", DbType.Int32).Value = shift.Break;
    InsertCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In this way, the work to transform your values in the correct format expected by the database engine is no more in the hands of the formatting rules of the string concatenation but is the database engine itself that receives the date and time values and use them as it likes without error in conversions.

As a by-product, your query is a lot more clear and less prone to errors like the one you have made missing to pass the date that was expected as second value.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! I know about SQL injections, but this app won't take any user input, so I am not so worried there

Comment: @MattBaech please test the two parameters of type Time. I have no way to test it here, in case of errors try using directly the DbType.Date also for them

Comment: well, first of all DbType is not recognized within SQLite, so had to import 'System.Data;'

When I run it i get the following error:
Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Comment: Ah, you wrote $sdate and $edate instead of $stime and $etime, and I just blindly copied... Thanks, after I changed it it worked perfectly.

Comment: Uh, it's late here, time to go to bed. See you again on SO.

Comment: just to learn something, how come this worked but not my code? Even though its frowned upon, my insert string didn't contain any errors did it ? ( I deleted the duplicate EmployeeID)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of inserting using **SQLite**

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(';');
    shift.EmployeeID = Int32.Parse(fields[0]);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[1], "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.Date = dt;
    DateTime st = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[2], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.StartTime = st;
    DateTime et = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[3], "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    shift.EndTime = et;
    shift.Break = Int32.Parse(fields[4]);

    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection { ConnectionString = "ConnectionString" })
    {
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand { Connection = con })
        {
           con.Open();

           try
           {
              command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Shifts 
                                      (EmployeeID, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Break) 
                                      VALUES (@eid, @date, @stime, @etime, @break)";
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", shift.EmployeeID);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", shift.Date);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stime", shift.StartTime);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etime", shift.EndTime);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@break", shift.Break);
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             command.Parameters.Clear();
           }
           catch(SQLiteException ex)
           {
              throw ex; 
           }

        }
    }

}
```